# WPF Window Navigation using MVVM but not frameworks(not even MSFT)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, navigation

Just so that this is not tagged as a duplicate. I found lot of similar questions but they relied on usage of frameworks (either 3rd part or MSFT based). Also some suggested the inbuilt page navigation feature which is not what I am looking for.

Now coming back to the original question.

I am developing a WPF application with MVVM pattern, no Prism or any framework, just *basic MVVM* concept. I wish to navigate from Window 1 (`Login`) to Window 2 (`MainWindow`) and then come back to Window1 (`Logout`). I am trying to understand what would be best way to achieve this. I am not looking for a workaround but rather the *conceptual way* to handle this situation to better understand MVVM.

Comment: Best?  That's relative.  You want to do it with two windows, but I think that sucks. I'd show the login form in the UI of the application, then hide it when the user has logged in.

Comment: Yep, MVVM looks really strange with multiple windows...

Comment: You can check my article here https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Simple-navigation-2be2ef4a

Comment: @Will by "Best" I mean conceptually best. I am not asking this as a means to finish off some task but rather as an enhancement to my knowledge of MVVM. Looking for expert viewpoints.

Comment: Its not just 2 screens, well just 3-4 actually but all major screens. Manually just hiding it seems practical but I thought maybe there would be a better way considering its WPF.

Comment: Thanks for the link @AyyappanSubramanian. I came across this approach earlier but to be frank this is not actually navigation. Its the same window and just multiple user controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Window` navigation is slightly tricky with the MVVM pattern. The pattern is best suited to `Page` navigation, or a SPA (Single Page Application) user interface.

However, that doesn't mean it can't be done without a framework.

---

First and foremost, it's important to note that no code-behind is **not** the point in MVVM. It's about putting code *where it belongs*. So, opening a `Window` from a click event of a `Button` is totally valid, as it's part of the **view related code**.

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   MyView view = new MyView();
   view.Show();
}
```

Try not to get bogged down with the idea that code-behind is bad code, because it isn't.

---

In order to keep your view model separated from the *window opening logic*, it would be a good idea to encapsulate this in a **service**. Let's look at a very simple example:

```
public interface IWindowService
{
    void OpenView(object viewModel);
}

public class WindowService
{
    public void OpenView(object viewModel)
    {
        //Use reflection to get the view based on the view model name.

        //Open the view

        //Set the DataContext to be the view model.
    }
}
```

*Note: I'm not going to bother with too much code, this is purely from a conceptual point of view.*

The service is pretty simple, there is a method which requires a view model, and based on this, it will find the associated view, open it, and set the `DataContext`. Simple really.

This service can be expanded to handle **dialogs** and whatnot.

In order to make use of this service, we need to *inject* it into the **View Model**, something like this should do it:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    private IWindowService _WindowService;

    public MyViewModel(IWindowService windowService)
    {
        _WindowService = windowService;
    }

    ...
}
```

You can make use of `Dependency Injection` to inject the service into the view model, see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921152.aspx). An important note here is that I am using an `interface`, this allows me to abstract away the implementation of the window service, which is certainly a good thing.

All that's left is to open a view, which can be done by calling the `OpenView` method:

```
SomeOtherViewModel myOtherViewModel = new SomeOtherViewModel();
_WindowService.OpenView(myOtherViewModel);
```

That's pretty much it.